# Terraform aws_cloudfront_distribution - How to set Compress objects automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I don't see a way in [Terraform aws_cloudfront_distribution documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_distribution) to set "Compress objects automatically" to "Yes" (or "true"). I can't tell which setting it is. The documentation shows a `compress` option but that seems to apply to cache behavior.

[image: Compress objects automatically]

So I need to set what?

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "instance" {
    ?what? = true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To configure the compression by default, you can use the following code:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "name" {
  enabled = false
  
  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods        = ["value"]
    cached_methods         = ["value"]
    target_origin_id       = "value"
    viewer_protocol_policy = "value"
    compress               = true # <---- add this
  }
  
  origin {
    domain_name = "value"
    origin_id   = "value"
  }
  
  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "value"
    }
  }
  
  viewer_certificate {
   ...
  }
}
```

The same can be configured for ordered cache behavior as well. The `value` in the fields is just a placeholder.